# First and last prime numbers with prime digits of range

Tags: code-golf, number, primes

## Challenge

For a given positive integers range, find the first and last prime number entirely composed of prime number digits, exceptionally including 0 (for the **digits**, a range of 0-2 should output 2-2). The range is inclusive. If no number is found, the expected output is 0. If there is only one such number, the expected output is that number twice.

## Examples

- For the range 1–100, the first prime number is 2 and the last is 73 (7 and 3 are prime numbers).
- For the range 70–80, the first prime number is 73 and the last is also 73 (Since there is only one correct number in the given range, we return it twice).
- For the range 190–200, there is no correct answer, so you return 0.
- For the range 2000-2100, the first prime number is 2003 and the last is 2053 (we omit the digit 0, but all the other digits are prime)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes win!

All standard loopholes apply.

## Input

- You are free to accept two integers as input however you may see fit, stack, function argument(s), CLI argument, stdin.
- You **must** only receive two integers.

## Output

- You **must** either return the result (a tuple, an array, multi-return if your language supports it), leave it on the stack, or print it (in this case, they must be separated somehow).
- The order of the outputs is irrelevant.
- You are allowed leading/trailing brackets and newlines.
- You must return two numbers, if there is an answer, even if they are the same.
- You must return 0 if there is no answer.

Comment: Just to make sure, if I'm returning a list of integers when there are answers, I can return a list containing just 0 when there are no answers? I don't need to return `0` instead of `[0]`?

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 123 bytes

```python
def f(a,b):r=[i for i in range(a,b+1)if(set(`i`)<=set('02357'))>any(i%k<1for k in range(3,i))];return len(r)and(r[0],r[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwEEX3nmI2xQxNIVGK1movIgEjJm2wRJmmC09vEzfdPf68B7Nu4bX4Yt8nY8EyzUdsqOsd2IXAgfNA2j9NOpwlOss@JrDBDdh2iXJRlNcqR3xovzF3mluZwvkfltwhqjuZ8CUPb@MZofYTo14oTv1FKtxTojmMqeqZ5CCFQA6sEhzqg@QtYhFX1WQAKzkfjm9hxF3yqGfRrUWWvKj9AA)

Comment: [122 bytes in Python 3](https://tio.run/##Rc7BDoIwEATQu1@xF8Ou1qSFGBTBH2k4lADaYApZ64EQvr1SL94mM3nJTLN/ji4Loe166NGIhgqutIV@ZLBgHbBxjy4OR0W2x@Xw9oyW1rJaDolMs3OerHQ3bka7H0oV3fB3mbBE9Y07/2EHr84hk3Etspa1YH1SNYVIjIAmKo1KgJKSBGAuBVx@SV23mG5tXewAJrbOA8a30BCFLw)

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 6, <s>105</s> <s>94</s> <s>90</s> 86 bytes

```
{my @b=grep {is-prime all($_,|.comb>>.Int Xor 2)},$^a..$^b;say @b??"@b[0] @b[*-1]"!!0}
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

Takes the range **[a-b]** in currying syntax `(a)(b)`. Returns either a 2-element array or **0**.

```js
n=>g=(m,a=0)=>n>m?a:g(m-1,(P=d=>m%--d?P(d):d>1|/[14689]/.test(m))(m)?a:[m,a[1]||m])
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>g=(m,a=0)=>n>m?a:g(m-1,(P=d=>m%--d?P(d):d>1|/[14689]/.test(m))(m)?a:[m,a[1]||m])

console.log(f(1)(100))
console.log(f(70)(80))
console.log(f(190)(200))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 91 bytes

```
If[(s=Select[Range@##,(p=PrimeQ)@#&&And@@((p@#||#<1)&/@IntegerDigits@#)&])!={},MinMax@s,0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcw/CwIhGIDxvW8RgigIaUsFCW/QcsNBf0a5Qa5XT0g5Toeg67PbLUHjjweeaMuA0ZbQ2@p0bZxhWd/xiX0xN5s8AiGCjfoyhYhXDoTSU3oAMDYCmWdyVJxuoEkFPU7n4EPJQDjt@Fq/P6INqbUvyEJ2tC6LVMAZJZSU3erHnRT7P6qDFNul1y8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
æRµDo2ÆPẠµÐf.ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//w6ZSwrVEbzLDhlDhuqDCtcOQZi7hu4v///8xMDD/MQ)

#### How it works

```
æRµDo2ÆPẠµÐf.ị ~ Full program.

æR             ~ Inclusive prime range.
  µ      µÐf   ~ Only keep those which satisfy a condition.
   Do2ÆPẠ      ~ The filter condition:
   D             ~ The decimal digits of the current number.
    o2           ~ Logical or with 2 (maps 0 to 2 and any other digit to itself).
      ÆP         ~ Is prime (element-wise)?
        Ạ        ~ Check whether all the digits satisfy the condition.
            .ị ~ Get the element at modular index 0.5. Some details:
                 ~ Jelly is 1-indexed, so 1 gives us the first element, whilst 0
                   gives us the last element.
                 ~ If the ceil and the floor of the given number N don't match, 
                   then Jelly returns the items at indexes floor(N) and ceil(N).
                 ~ If the list is empty, this yields 0, hence it is very convenient.
```

---

If taking the whole range would be allowed (although I think it should not be), then 12 bytes:

```
Do2,ÆPȦµÐf.ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc@tbYNRDIXhVTyAFdW/t@EZIDwKbEH1ScVdoKQkU2SDorKEdI1McvNeYORHxz4fb9v2Nefh0/X@ffy/3n7vl/fd4@9nznkyFVcJlVQplVYZKq8qexV7YdgbwBAGMYyBDGUwwznOVw7OcY5znOMc5zjHBS5wsQ7iAhe4wAUucIFLXOISl@szXOISl7jEJa5whStc4WpVwBWucIUrXOMa17jGNa5XV1zjGte4gRu4gRu4kecn)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fc@7TYNRDIDRVTyAhfDzJj0D0EcpKKBA/wIsQEOTEbJEGtIlk2SSm@8WtmT5yI/vz237mfN2uf@@f7yRHv9nitPXy@P6N@c8mIqrhEqqlEqrDJWdyl7FXgn6BjCEQQxjIEMZzHCO8zUH5zjHOc5xjnOc4wIXuFgLcYELXOACF7jAJS5xict1GS5xiUtc4hJXuMIVrnC1XsAVrnCFK1zjGte4xjWu16@4xjWucQM3cAM3cCOPTw) Although it isn't super similar. Should I just post it myself? You can take it if you want but let me know if you're going to keep your solution.

Comment: OP says `For a given positive integers range`. I'll ask to clarify

Comment: @dylnan note that your version is invalid nonetheless (`0` is the exception from the challenge, because it should be treated as a prime digit for some reason). Anyway, I posted a shorter *and* valid version

Comment: Oh I thought the 0 is prime rule had been changed

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

Using my initial approach turns out to be shorter.

```
.x,eKfP#I_M-+TjT;0}EQhKZ
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.x%2CeKfP%23I_M-%2BTjT%3B0%7DEQhKZ&input=100%0A1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=100%0A1%0A%0A80%0A70%0A%0A200%0A190%0A%0A2100%0A2000%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

(I was just updating to 23 but [Steven beat me to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150520/first-and-last-prime-numbers-with-prime-digits-of-range/151011?noredirect=1#comment369324_151011))

```
?KfP#I_M-+TjT;0}FQhM_BK0
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FKfP%23I_M-%2BTjT%3B0%7DFQhM_BK0&input=100%2C200&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C+100%0A70%2C80%0A190%2C200%0A2000%2C2100&debug=0)**

Natually, `hM_BK` can be replaced by `,hKeK`.

#### 25 bytes

```
.x,eKf.AmP_|d2+TjT;}EQhKZ
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.x%2CeKf.AmP_%7Cd2%2BTjT%3B%7DEQhKZ&input=100%0A1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=100%0A1%0A%0A80%0A70%0A%0A200%0A190%0A%0A2100%0A2000%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

#### 26 bytes

```
|>2.<f.AmP_|d2+TjT;*2}EQ1Z
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7C%3E2.%3Cf.AmP_%7Cd2%2BTjT%3B%2a2%7DEQ1Z&input=100%0A1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=100%0A1%0A%0A80%0A70%0A%0A200%0A190%0A%0A2100%0A2000%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

```
|>2.<fP#I_M|R2+TjT;*2}EQ1Z
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7C%3E2.%3CfP%23I_M%7CR2%2BTjT%3B%2a2%7DEQ1Z&input=100%0A1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=100%0A1%0A%0A80%0A70%0A%0A200%0A190%0A%0A2100%0A2000%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

---

#### How they work

```
.x,eKfP#I_M-+TjT;0}EQhKZ ~ Full program. Q, E = first, second inputs

.x                     Z ~ Try-catch block. If the code errors, output 0.
     f            }EQ    ~ Filter the range [E ... Q] for (uses a variable T):
            +TjT;          ~ Append T to the list of its digits.
           -     0         ~ Remove the zeros.
         _M                ~ Multiply each by -1 (for primality testing).
        I                  ~ Check if the result is invariant over...
      P#                   ~ Removing non-prime items.
    K                    ~ Assigned the filtered range to a variable K.
  ,e                     ~ Pair the last element of K with...
                     hK  ~ Its first element.
```

---

```
|>2.<f.AmP_|d2+TjT;*2}EQ1Z ~ Full program.

                   *2}EQ   ~ Inclusive range, repeated twice..
     f                     ~ Filter, using T as the current number.
                jT;        ~ Base-10 digits of T.
              +T           ~ Concatenated with T.
        mP_|d2             ~ Prime check after performing OR 2 (makes 0 be treated as prime)
      .A                   ~ Do all satisfy this condition?
   .<                   1  ~ Rotate by one place cyclically to the left.
 >2                        ~ Last two elements (ignored if there aren't enough)
|                        Z ~ Logical or with 0.
```

Comment: [Outgolfed by 1, and I think there's still more to save](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151011)

Comment: This one doesn't return two instances of [73] in the [70, 80] test case.

Comment: Outgolfed you back by 1, now at 25.

Comment: @StevenH. Outgolfed you back by 1, now at 24.

Comment: The competition's getting intense... at 23!

Comment: I am going to bed now, continuing this  tomorrow evening ;D (though I think our solutions are slowly tending towards optimality)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
⟦₂{ṗṗᵐ}ˢ⟨⌋≡⌉⟩|∧0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@amqof7pwOQlsn1J5e9Gj@ikc93Y86Fz7q6Xw0f2XNo47lBv//RxtaGugYGRjE/o8CAA)

The completely non-sensical "return 0 if there's no prime" makes us lose 3 bytes (`|∧0`) for no reason (it would return `false.` if we didnt add them)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₂                Range from the smallest element of the input to the biggest
  {   }ˢ          Select on that range:
   ṗ                Numbers that are primes
    ṗᵐ              And whose digits are primes
        ⟨   ⟩     Fork on this new list:
         ⌋          Minimum
           ⌉        maximum
          ≡         Do nothing and return [Minimum, Maximum]
             |∧0  If all of this fails (i.e. the list after selection is empty), return 0
```

Comment: Invalid because it doesn't handle the digit 0 as being prime (as specified in the challenge). Thus, it fails for `[2000, 2100]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
Do2ÆPẠ
æRÇÐf.ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//RG8yw4ZQ4bqgCsOmUsOHw5BmLuG7i////zcw/zgw)

```
æRÇÐf.ị            Main link
æR                 Prime range
   Ðf              Filter the range with...
  Ç                The helper link
      ị            At index (decimal, returns [xs[floor], xs[ceil]], otherwise 0)
     .             0.5

Do2ÆPẠ             Helper link
D                  For each decimal
 o2                Replace 0s with 2s, an actual prime prime (could be 3, 5, or 7).
   ÆP              Filter primes (1 if true, 0 if false)
     Ạ             Check if all are true
```

Thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) for the help fixing a bug.
Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for the `.ị` trick.

Comment: Would `ṙ-ḣ2` work for `Ḣ,Ṫ` to fix it (might have to modify a little more)?

Comment: @Zacharý that gives the output in the wrong order, though. And it doesn't seem to work :\

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The Jelly room led me to the same solution. Thanks!

Comment: `.ị` might work as well (kind of stolen from Mr. XCoder)

Comment: You're right! That's nice.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 85 Bytes

I know there is already a similar answer, but the approach here is quite different.

```
MinMax@Cases[Range@##,x_/;PrimeQ@x&&DisjointQ@@IntegerDigits/@{x,14689}]/.{_,∞}->0&
```

This 83 character answer will paste and run in Mathematica.  The TIO site doesn't know how to interpret ∞.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 87 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{(z=(a..b).select{|x|(2...x).none?{|r|x%r<1}&&/[14689]/!~"%d"%x})[0]?(z.minmax):0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc3RCsIgGEDhV7HBhoL90xG1RWsPIl5obRCkjVVgU3t1k@4@zs1Z3vqTpj5tz4pqj9ceKwBN4Dnex8vLBxdwAwCOgH3YcfBhCa5cTjxWVS34bt92st58i/JalC4SweSAVzA3a5QjRxaTEJwizpikSBwYRe1fvMtscpVg1OxDfgc0o0lkyJh@)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 36 bytes

```
),>{mp},{s{_!\~mp|}%1-!},_{_0=\W=}0?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31DB0MBAU8euOregVqe6uDpeMaYut6CmVtVQV7FWJ7463sA2Jty21sD@/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>68 66 65 61</s>  58 bytes

```perl6
{($_=($^a..$^b).grep({.is-prime&&/^<[02357]>+$/})[0,*-1])[1]??$_!!0}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoIwGIXv9xS/NGQrnf8mucLMBxEVsxFCkigFEj770gtB6OZcnPPxnc70z8gS8h4MfCJRx6Qdwa1fdwOJ/TJaJowWlRC0uHHx6E3HvqIZ/K5vWuO6QXHJUIVHnV8PNJh4ht7elznPZJ6mtHQcnOxQjbD4GABIbwlE4DHsgCkPdMjJltC4IKeV0OEfIs8LolYJbra5nDe1OUCcBQqV5vYH)

```perl6
{($_=($^a..$^b).grep({.is-prime&&!/<[14689]>/})[0,*-1])[1]??$_!!0}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCoMwFET3nuJLgyRF408sRrHWg4iKtaEIlYrSgohnt2YhCN3MYubxptfDK1wt6zNq@Ia8SaxuAqd5PzSk60xJlVJS1pyT8s74c9A9nXk7ev3QdtpxbP@ai0sYxcXNX1iO7tkTBctFkWWksm1c1rGewNgoAAjXBCKwBE5ApQsqYNaRUGiQaCdU8IeI2CByl@Bh28ptk4cDxE0gUSq2/gA)

```perl6
{($_=($^a..$^b).grep({.is-prime*!/<[14689]>/})[0,*-1])[1]??$_!!0}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCoMwFET3nuJLQ0lE408sRrHWg4iKtaEIlYrSgohnt2YhCN3MYubxptfDK1wt6zNq@Ia8SaxugnPzfmhI15mSKqWkrDkn5Z3x56B7OvN29Pqh7bRj@9dcXMIoLm7@wnJ0HU8ULBdFlpHKtnFZx3oCI6MAIFwTiMASOAGVLqiAWUdCoUGinVDBHyJig8hdgodtK7dNHg4QN4FEqdj6Aw)

```perl6
{($_=($^a..$^b).grep({.is-prime*!/<[14689]>/}))??.[0,*-1]!!0}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoIwGIXv9xS/JLGJzn8znGLmg4iF2QghSZQCEZ99uQtB6OZcnPPxnV4Pr9gQ8hk1fGPeZKSb4Ni8HxpyM1P3llP3WnPuXu@MPwfd05m3Y9APbac9JzyX4hQnaXUJF8aKgpfoe4GoHAcXM9YTWBEFAOHbQASWwQGo9EFFjOwJhRZJNkJFf4hILSI3Ce62tVw3uTtAXAUSpWLmBw)

```perl6
{($_=grep {.is-prime*!/<[14689]>/},$^a..$^b)??.[0,*-1]!!0}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoIwGIXv9xS/JOFkzn8znGLmg4iF2QghSZQCEZ99uQtB6OZcnPPxnV4Pr9gQ8hk1fGPeZKSb4Ni8HxpyM3vuLX8OuoeZt2PQD22nfSc8l@IUJ2l1CRfmXmvO3eudFgUvkfmBqBwHFzPWE1iLBwCC2UAEmsEBPMlARZTsCYUWSTZCRX@ISC0iNwnutrVcN7k7QFwFEqWi5gc)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with two placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣

  (
    $_ =  # store the list in ｢$_｣ for later use

      grep {
          .is-prime

        *              # True * True == 1 (all others equal 0)

          !/<[14689]>/ # doesn't contain a non-prime other than 0
      },

      $^a .. $^b       # inclusive Range

  )            # is the list Truish (not empty)
  ?? .[0,*-1]  # if so output the first and last values (from ｢$_｣)
  !! 0         # otherwise return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 79 + 2 (`-ap`) = 81 bytes

```perl
map{$f=0|sqrt;1while$_%$f--;$s||=$_,$\=-$_ if!$f&&!/[14689]/}$F[0]..$F[1];$_=$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVBCsIwEAXQq7Tw7cqkM2BFCdm68wQ1hC4aDNQ2NgUXxqs7@jYvjevUiTyG9EawVPJz3Qy/7nEa4XcIShnkUiz8Hjer4KsYaoSmqdueD8fT2bUfXHpyWv9jZ@AtsghXTN8lbXGZs6hrp4lJ1JB@)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>165</s> <s>164</s> <s>163</s> 152 bytes

```java
(a,b)->{for(;a<=b&p(a);a++);for(;b>a&p(b);b--);return a>b?"0":a+" "+b;}boolean p(int n){int i=1;for(;n%++i%n>0;);return!(n+"").matches("[02357]+")|i<n;}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVHBbsIwDL3vK7xITInSViloYlug@4Jx2RFxcErYwlq3agPTxPrtXVrYGaQ4lu3nZz17j0eMq9rSfvvV5wW2Lbyho9MdgCNvmx3mFlZDCPDuG0cfkPNQAYyG3wgdSl2w8FZAsISeY2REnJ12VcM1LpbmoeYoNEop9JgzGYZUaDVxLHRj/aEhwMy8MsVeUDJg0uhOm6oqLBLU4zwSp8G5ZXomoYmUbkKZ0v8U95wkYyIp0eeftuVsraazx/lGMvHrFqS7HqA@mMLl0Hr0wR0rt4UyyOVnaesNoDhrHZYAZZBD9nsM@Kg0LOGn9bZMqoNP6tDjC@JlQknO0yhVSlxDzVX0dB2VPqtoegNbwATgLXPTaHqdLUpn4nLQrv8D)

```java
(a,b)->{           // Method with two integer parameters and String return-type
                   //  (Input `a` is the lowest input, input `b` is the highest input)
  for(;a<=b        //  Increase `a` as long as it's smaller than or equal to `b`,
       &p(a);a++); //  and it's not a prime, and not all of its digits are prime-digits
  for(;b>a         //  Decrease `b` as long as it's larger than `a`,
       &p(b);b--); //  and it's not a prime, and not all of its digits are prime-digits
  return a>b?      //  If `a` is now larger than `b`:
    "0"            //   Return 0, because nothing is found
   :               //  Else:
    a+" "+b;}      //   Return the resulting `a` and `b`

// Separated method that'll result in true if the integer is NOT a prime number,
// or any of its digits are NOT prime numbers (excluding 0)
boolean p(int n){int i=1;for(;n%++i%n>0;);return!(n+"").matches("[02357]+")|i<n;}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks. Been able to save 11 more bytes by using a different prime checker that only works for positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>142</s> <s>131</s> 125 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@a b#l=[n\\n<-[a..b]|and[gcd p n<2&&or[c==k\\k<-:"02357"]\\p<-[1..n-1],c<-:toString n]]
|l>[]=[hd l,last l]=[0]
```

Ungolfed:

```
import StdEnv
fn start finish
    # primes
        = [ n
            \\
            n <- [start..finish]
            | and [ gcd p n == 1 && isMember c ['0','2','3','5','7'] 
                \\
                p <- [1..n-1],
                c <-: toString n
            ]
        ]
    | isEmpty primes
        = [0]
    = [hd primes, last primes]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY1BC4IwGEDv/YoPA08qcxFBuPBQh6Cbx22Hz81MnJ@iKwj87S2Pj/fgGdcghWG0b9fAgB2FbpjG2UPl7Y0@uxKh3jshSSkqUolZVusVycrWWJiACh7H4yyNEL1SfZGeI8YPx1OklZq2Ps8ySnOdmM34sfJzRy2Q1rvVXaQW8mXBJQ4XD24jpkPlcZsLKIEzxoDnjIWfeTpsl5DeH@H6JRw6s/wB)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
.xhM_BfP#I_M #+TjT;}FQ0
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.xhM_BfP%23I_M+%23%2BTjT%3B%7DFQ0&input=100%2C200&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C100%0A%0A70%2C80%0A%0A190%2C200%0A%0A2000%2C2100%0A&debug=0&input_size=2) Returns [2003,2053] for the last test case, since 2053 is prime.

Comment: Haha, invalid. Returns `[0, 0]` instead of `0`

Comment: Ah, shoot.  I'll fix that.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Fixed!

Comment: God damn it I was just updating with [23 too](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.xeM_BfP%23I_M-%2BTjT%3B0%7DFQ0&input=100%2C200&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C+100%0A70%2C80%0A190%2C200%0A2000%2C2100&debug=0)

Comment: I thought you said you were going to bed... You tricky you :P

Comment: I strived to outgolf you first, it’s just too fun :-)